# Sunpot search not searching. "rake sunspot:solr:reindex" aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot

I'm attempting to use Sunspot/Solr to search all User name and content associated with their profile (named 'bio'). The search box is at `http://localhost:3000/users`. I'm clearly not doing something right because when i search a name i get taken back to page 1 of Users with the full list i.e no search has been executed. I'm stumped.

When i run `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

```
undefined method `title' for #<User:0x007f9e9ea52e60>
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:436:in `method_missing'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:131:in `method_missing'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/data_extractor.rb:17:in `value_for'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/field_factory.rb:58:in `populate_document'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:100:in `block in prepare'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:99:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:99:in `prepare'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:26:in `block in add'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:26:in `map'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:26:in `add'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:91:in `index'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `index'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/retry_5xx_session_proxy.rb:17:in `method_missing'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `index'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot.rb:184:in `index'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:261:in `block (2 levels) in solr_index'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:365:in `solr_benchmark'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:260:in `block in solr_index'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:75:in `find_in_batches'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:70:in `find_in_batches'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:68:in `find_in_batches'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `find_in_batches'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:259:in `solr_index'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:203:in `solr_reindex'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:64:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.0.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:reindex => sunspot:reindex
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**model/bio.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    searchable do
  text :title, :name, :content, :body
  end


end
```

**bio_controllers.rb (this is a separate file from user_controller.rb)**

```
class BioController < ApplicationController

def index

  @search = users.search do
    fulltext params[:search] 
  end

  @users = @search.results
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
 <% provide(:title, 'All users') %>

    <%= form_tag users_path, :method => :get do %>

      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      </p>
    <% end %>


    <h1>All users</h1>

    <%= will_paginate %>

    <ul class="users">
      <%= render @users %>
    </ul>

    <%= will_paginate %>
```

**db/migrate/...**

```
class AddBioToUserProfile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :bio, :string
  end
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
  text :name, :bio, :users
  end


  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  #VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    #format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end



end
```

Comment: Did you actually started sunspot before reindexing?

Comment: @ zrl3dx I didn't. I've just started sunspot and then reindexed. The result is above in the first block quote.

Comment: Add to  your model `attr_accessible` :title (and of course you should have such column generated by migration).

Comment: I thought `attr_accessible` isn't required in Rails 4.0? I've added the db/migrate file above

Comment: Sorry, i've forgotten that's rails 4.0, you're using strong parameters there.

Comment: Either change column name to `title` or change `searchable` block from `title` to `bio`.

Comment: Neither worked i'm afraid. Those change are in models/bio.rb right?

Comment: Yes (which should be named `user.rb` btw), your model should respond to fields names from searchable block, either as simple accessors from db mapped by ActiveRecord or some methods returning appropriate results.

Comment: I changed the `searchable block` in `bio.rb` to `text :name, :bio` which allowed me to reindex. However the search is still not successful. I create a separate model file to `user.rb`. So you're saying `bio.rb` should be part of `user.rb`?

Comment: I don't know your design, but if you have model named `user.rb` it should contains class `User`, if you want to add another one change the file name accordingly (or maybe that's just a mistake in writing here, I don't know). What is returning solr in logs when you perform search?

Comment: `bio.rb` is separate to `user.rb`. I don't know how to merge them. How do access solr logs? If you mean in the terminal window, the server GET request is successful. I've added my `user.rb` file above.

Comment: @zrl3dx I've merged `bio.rb` with `user.rb` and i've pasted 'user.rb'above

Comment: If field `:users` is not giving you any error what is returned now when you add and save new data, reindex and do query?

Comment: Reindexing results in: `Skipping progress bar: for progress reporting, add gem 'progress_bar' to your Gemfile`

I think the problem is the `user.rb` file. When adding 
`searchable do
  text :name, :bio, :users
  end`

it caused errors.

Comment: Addd that gem (`gem 'progress_bar'`) to your Gemfile and try again, solr needs it for showing fancy bar during indexing.

Comment: No change after adding the gem

Comment: No change in what? Still get `Skipping progress..`?

Comment: No progress bar visible, no search occurring. Not getting `Skipping progress` now.

Comment: Call `@search.results.inspect` and show output.

Comment: Where do i do that? Sorry, still quite new to Rails

Comment: you can put it even into view `index.html.erb`, just wrap it into `erb` markers, i.e. `<%= @search.results.inspect %>`, you will see the output in your browser.

Comment: Causes error `NoMethodError in Users#index`

Comment: Put it into `index` rendered by `index` aaction from BioController.

Comment: That's `index.html.erb`. I placed it there and it caused an error.

Comment: But error comes from `Users` (you've got also probably mixed plural and singular names, controllers should be plural, models singular, both classes and file names) not from `Bio`. Put also whole error, unfortunately we can't move this on chat, we shouldn't do such extensive talk in comments.

Comment: Ok, i'll have a look through everything and see where i've gone wrong. If i find the issue i'll comment back here. Thanks for your help.